# How to alter triggers on multiple tables in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a bunch of generated tables which each have a trigger named `SOMETHINGCONSTANT_TRIGGERINGTABLE`. Is there a way to enable or disable all of these triggers at once?

Comment: Is PL/SQL acceptable? If it is, please consider adding the relevant tag to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
declare
  stmt_ varchar2(4000);
begin
  for rec_ in (select TRIGGER_NAME from USER_TRIGGERS
               where trigger_name LIKE 'SOMETHINGCONSTANT%') loop

    stmt_ := 'ALTER TRIGGER ' || rec_.TRIGGER_NAME || ' ENABLE';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt_;

  end loop;
end;
```

I believe you have all the trigger and tables in the same user, else you need to login into the particular user and run the query if there are multiple users involved.